# Creating an option type menu in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is what I'm talking about, only just hiding half of the view that called it:

[image]

I've searched on the internet for hours, but I seem to be missing some sort of key word. I've searched: iOS Menu, iOS Overlay Menu, iOS Options Menu, iOS Sharing Menu (as it resembled the old one), iOS Called Menu and variations of all of those. It would be extremely helpful if someone could tell me the name of this type of menu or possible explain how to make one.

Comment: it is called `UIActionSheet`

Comment: @xlc Thank you so much. I've been trying to figure that out for over an hour (not even including 15 minutes here and there yesterday).

Comment: ios sliding menu, ios sliding option menu, ios option menu. Only three tries, 30 minutes :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's called a [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html).